# Get dates from date to date in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have two dates starting date and end date. How to **get range of days** from these two dates?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should user [DatePeriod class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) and example:

```
$period = new \DatePeriod(
            new \DateTime('2010-10-01'),
            new \DateInterval('P1D'),
            new \DateTime('2010-10-05')
        );
```

Comment: Ok, but when I try to pass it to my view I'm using @foreach($period as $period)
     {{$period}}
@endforeach and I have an error "htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"

Comment: Okay, I've solved it out.